# I don't like speaking in public (is public an adjective or noun here?)

Tags: adjectives

I speak to the public.
I am speaking in public. It doesn't seem grammatically correct at all

I am speaking "in public" .
I am speaking "out in the open." We don't say, 'I am speaking "out in open."

Speaking in public is correct English seemingly, but it doesn't come across as being so (correct) upon further scrutiny. Kindly dissuade me from my conclusion, for which I personally have no resolution.

Comment: If you look in any dictionary, you will see that "in public" is a **set phrase**. It means in the presence of other people which form a kind of "public". "In public" concerns any people, not a particular group of people, so it does not need a definite article. You also have phrases like "in fact", "in truth".

Comment: _In public_ and its opposite, _in private_, are perfectly standard expressions.

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence

> I am speaking to the public.

"public" is a noun. It's the collection of people you are speaking to.

In the sentence

> I am speaking in public.

"in public" is an adverbial phrase modifying the verb. It describes where you are speaking, not who you are speaking to.